# open_basedir for php running as FastCGI

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, fastcgi

I've installed some time ago Apache and php as a fastcgi module

```
root@company# apt-get install apache2 apache2-suexec libapache2-mod-fcgid php5-cgi

root@company# dpkg-query -l '*apache2*' 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold 
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend 
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad) 
||/ Name                           Version                        Description 
+++-==============================-==============================-============================================================================ 
ii  apache2              2.2.20-1ubuntu1.2         Apache HTTP Server metapackage 
ii  apache2-mpm-worker   2.2.20-1ubuntu1.2         Apache HTTP Server - high speed threaded model 
ii  apache2-suexec       2.2.20-1ubuntu1.2  Standard suexec program for Apache 2 mod_suexec 
ii  apache2-utils        2.2.20-1ubuntu1.2         utility programs for webservers 
ii  apache2.2-bin        2.2.20-1ubuntu1.2         Apache HTTP Server common binary files 
ii  apache2.2-common     2.2.20-1ubuntu1.2         Apache HTTP Server common files 
ii  libapache2-mod-fcgid 1:2.3.6-1+squeeze1build0.11.10 an alternative module compat with mod_fastcgi 

root@company# dpkg-query -l '*php*' 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold 
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend 
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad) 
||/ Name                              Version                           Description 
+++-=================================-=================================-================================================================================== 
un  php-pear                    <none>                         (no description available) 
ii  php5-cgi  5.3.6-13ubuntu3.7  server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (CGI binary) 
ii  php5-common     5.3.6-13ubuntu3.7  Common files for packages built from the php5 source 
un  php5-json                  <none>                            (no description available) 
un  php5-mhash                 <none>                            (no description available) 
un  php5-suhosin               <none>                            (no description available) 
un  phpapi-20090626            <none>                            (no description available) 

root@company# dpkg-query -l '*fcgi*' 
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold 
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend 
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad) 
||/ Name                              Version                           Description 
+++-=================================-=================================-================================================================================== 
ii  libapache2-mod-fcgid 1:2.3.6-1+squeeze1build0.11.10.1  an alternative module compat with mod_fastcgi
```

Now, I'm aware that I can't use this command in my virtual hosts:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/users/test"
```

A typical virtual host file in my case:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName test
 ServerAlias test
 ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/users/test/public_html/

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
 SuexecUserGroup test test
 <Directory /var/www/users/test/public_html/>
 Options +ExecCGI
 Options -Indexes
 AllowOverride None
 AddHandler fcgid-script .php
 FCGIWrapper /var/www/system/test/php-fcgi-starter .php
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 </Directory>
</IfModule>

 # ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
 # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
 ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

1) Any ideas as how to enable `open_basedir` and also allow my users to change `php.ini` which I define in their home (e.g. `/var/www/users/test`). A user should not alter my value even if he tries to edit `php.ini`.

Is this possible?
or, I should just forget user access to `php.ini` for all my users and change once-for-all his `php.ini`?(I can do that by simply relocating it-there is a fcgid wrapper script in such a setup as you know)

2) I would appreciate it if anyone could also give me some Apache2 directives that redirect all requests from:

```
http://www.test.com/a/new/post
```

to this one internally:

```
http://www.test.com/index.php?a/new/post
```

The following does not work-should give some parameters:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

(No I don't want to allow .htaccess files for reasons of speed)

Thanks!

**Comment on Question (2):** I noticed that this directive inside the `<Directory>` section achieves what I need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but behaves strangely with presenting the php image at (is not shown)

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

the link of this image at the echoed file is

```
<img border="0" src="/info.php?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42" alt="PHP Logo" />
```

any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you should have other people as users on a web server if you don’t know how to administrate/configure it properly …?

Comment: So what do you propose? Administration comes by inheritance or nationality?

Answer (score 0):

**Related with question (2):** it seems these directives really make the magic (see comments inside and after)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName test
 ServerAlias test
 ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/users/test/public_html/

 #the next line should be removed in production
 RewriteLog /var/www/users/test/public_html/rewrite.log
 RewriteLogLevel 9

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
 SuexecUserGroup test test
 <Directory /var/www/users/test/public_html/>
 Options +ExecCGI
 Options -Indexes
 AllowOverride None
 AddHandler fcgid-script .php
 FCGIWrapper /var/www/system/test/php-fcgi-starter .php
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all

 RewriteEngine On
 #next line introduces some behavior, see comment (1)
 #RewriteBase /

 #redirect non-existent files or, redirect existent
 #files with the execute bit set, see comment (2)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -x

 #under the above dir ("/var/www/users/test/public_html/")
 #there is a "php/tests/testApache.php" that catches all requests
 #for non-existent files or for executables,
 #L=last, NC=case-insensitive, NE=no hexcode escaping of the request uri
 #QSA=append query string from the original request uri to the resulted string
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ php/tests/testApache.php?$1 [NC,NE,L,QSA]

 </Directory>
</IfModule>

 #the next 2 lines should be removed in production
 ErrorLog /var/www/users/test/public_html/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/users/test/public_html/access.log combined

 ServerSignature Off

</VirtualHost>
```

**comment (1):** by investigating our "rewrite.log" file we see these differences after deleting time, sid, rid fields

```
root@localhost# diff 1.txt 2.txt
8,10c8
< 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2013: +0200] [test/sid#][rid#/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/users/test/public_html/] trying to replace prefix 
/var/www/users/test/public_html/ with /
< 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2013: +0200] [test/sid#][rid#/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/www/users/test/public_html/php/tests/te
stApache.php -> php/tests/testApache.php
< 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2013: +0200] [test/sid#][rid#/initial] (4) add subst prefix: php/tests/testApache.php -> /php/tests/testApache
.php
---
> 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2013: +0200] [test/sid#][rid#/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/users/test/public_html/] strip document_root prefi
x: /var/www/users/test/public_html/php/tests/testApache.php -> /php/tests/testApache.php
```

the left part (1.txt) comes with `RewriteBase /` in virtual hosts.

**comment (2):** by redirecting non-existent files all our images, .css, .js, .htm* files work as expected as long as the resource's path is given compared with the document root (in these virtual hosts is "/var/www/users/test/public_html/").
So, a test image is written:

```
echo '<img src="/wallpaper-10.jpg" alt="Christmas">';
```

and it is located at "/var/www/users/test/public_html/wallpaper-10.jpg".

Still waiting some responses on **question (1)**...